# Access the form that caused a post_save [Django]

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

Is there a way I can access the form that caused a `post_save`?

The use case is that I have a field (a checkbox) that isn't attached to a particular model, but it's an extra field in the form itself.

I want to know whether the field was checked or unchecked when the form got saved and the model stored, and imho the `post_save` signal is a good place to put the logic that should process that extra field.

I'm also open to suggestions where else I could put that piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

`post_save` won't know anything about any form that might have caused the model change.

If you want to access that checkbox value you need to do it in the form class itself. I would probably override the `clean()` method of the form, and check for the checkbox value in `cleaned_data['checkbox_field']` there, and then do whatever you need to with it.

Comment: The `clean` method will be called way too soon for my purpose. I need to do my logic after the model has been successfully saved.

Comment: Then you probably want to override the `save()` method on the form and put the logic there. Assuming you are using a `ModelForm`.

Comment: But doing business logic in the `save()` method of the form feels quite ugly.

Comment: I guess without knowing what you are doing it's hard to suggest anything else. I think you basically have three ugly options: squirrel that checkbox value away somewhere for later use, access `request.POST` directly in your view, or do your stuff in the form class somewhere. Or rethink your approach altogether.